# How do I expand a div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello all I have a div called “bar” that contains a SVG file of a rectangle. The rectangle is about 160px wide and 60px in height, a stroke of 4px with rounded corners. When the user double clicks on the green square I want the rectangle to expand downward on the Y axis, about 100px down to reveal the div called “circle”. When the user double clicks a second time I want the rectangle to scroll back up to the original size, hiding the circle div.I have tried using transform: scaleY() in the css, however it wraps  my rectangle and I do not know how to connect the css to the onclick js function. Can anyone help?

```js
const divItem = document.getElementById('divItem');
divItem.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  //when the user clicks the square I want the bar to expand  downward to reveal the circle div//
})
```

```css
#divItem{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: 55px;
}

/*.bar{
  transform: scaleY(3);
}*/
.circle{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  clip-path: circle();
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px; 
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Double Click Drop down</title>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="divItem"></div>
<div class="bar">
   <img src="SVG/bar.svg"> 
</div>
<div class="circle"></div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual method of manipulating the style of your page from Javascript is to add or remove classes from elements. Each element exposes a list of its classes in its [classList property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), and you can use the [toggle() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) of this list to add a class to the list if it not present, or remove it from the list if it is.

```
document.getElementById('divItem').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  document.querySelector('.bar').classList.toggle('expanded');
})
```

Then in the CSS you apply the scale to a `bar` element only when it is `expanded`.

```
.bar.expanded {
  transform: scaleY(3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked! However the circle div is still hidden onclick.

Comment: I was not able to understand that part of your question. Perhaps you could improve your snippet so that it better demonstrates the problem?